# Catching child process exceptions on windows

Tags: windows, debugging, exception, seh

i'm developing a multi-platform C++ fuzzing application. The app spawns a child process and checks whether it stopped unexpectedly. I've already managed to do this on linux, however, windows exception handling mechanism is making things hard for me.

My code right now does the following:
- Call CreateProcess to spawn the process.
- WaitForSingleObject to wait for it to terminate.
- Then call GetExitCodeProcess and check if the exit code corresponds to an exception.

Everything works as it should, i've tested it with a null dereferencing test application, and i can catch the exception gracefully. However, each time i test this, a Windows error message box spawns telling me to Send or Not Send the error report. Since the fuzzer is supposed to be an automatic testing application, i'd need to somehow disable this notification, so that even if an exception is caught, the fuzzer can continue testing.

I've already tried installing a SEH handler, but had no luck(apparently these handlers aren't inherited by child processes). I've read something about using vectored exception handling, but suppose it would be the same, i believe vector handlers aren't inherited.

Could anybody help me with this problem? I don't know what to search for, i've already googled a lot and haven't found anyhing.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Debug API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms809754.aspx) is one option. [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms679276%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) is a starting point in MSDN.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I had thought of using some debugging API, but thought some applications which use some anti-debugging mechanisms to avoid cracking and/or revering could modify their behaviour if they detect they're being debugged by the fuzzer. I suppose if i can't find another option, then i'll have to use this debugging mechanism.

Comment: all the more reason to shoot people who try to reverse-engineer proof their code.

Answer (score 2):

Following on frast's answer, you can spawn the process as a *child* of a process with a suitable [SetErrorMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680621%28v=VS.85%29.aspx). This (inheritable) setting determines which errors will result in dialogs popping out - I found your question while trying to achieve the exact same thing for an automated testing application.

To avoid any error dialogs, use

```
SetErrorMode(
    SEM_FAILCRITICALERRORS 
    | SEM_NOALIGNMENTFAULTEXCEPT 
    | SEM_NOGPFAULTERRORBOX 
    | SEM_NOOPENFILEERRORBOX);
```

Injection is probably overkill - better to use a wrapper process.

Comment: Can you share what is a wrapper process that can handle this?

Comment: "Wrapper" is a generic name for a process/function/method whose only goal is to call and later clean up another process/function/method. You can create a child process in windows using https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682512(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: I see. If the child app does SetErrorMode, we will still need the injection

Answer (score 1):

Try to inject the following code into your child process:

```
SetErrorMode(SEM_NOGPFAULTERRORBOX);
```

Lookup the details of [SetErrorMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680621%28VS.85%29.aspx) in MSDN.

Read about injection technique here:
[Injective Code inside Import Table](http://www.ntcore.com/files/inject2it.htm)